# PHP why unset do not makes memory free?

Tags: php, optimization

I have php application which should manage (export) big (huge) amount of data, and it has to be done on production... so I need to make as low memory usage as possible (main criteria).

Shortly say App exporting data in cycle, like

```
for($fileCounter=0;$fileCounter<=70;$fileCounter++) {
... HERE a lot of (more than 1K lines) huge work, many variables a lot of DB queries from another databases etc ...
}
```

I don't want to show here full logic because it can take a lot of time for other peoples, it's not the main point here.

Main point is, why if I will `unset()` all newly created variables during each iteration it does not decrease memory usage ? like this

```
for($fileCounter=0;$fileCounter<=70;$fileCounter++) {
    // optimization purpose
    $vars_at_start = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
    echo memory_get_peak_usage(true) . PHP_EOL;

... huge logic ...

    $vars_at_end = array_diff($vars_at_start, array_keys(get_defined_vars()));
    foreach($vars_at_end as $v) unset($v);
    unset($vars_at_end);
}
```

and how I could decrease memory usage ? if I need to use so many queries, variebles etc..

P.S. code is not mine :) and I don't want to rewrite it from scratch, I'm just looking for optimization direction.

without variables cleaning memory usage is next (it is measuring in the beginning of each iteration)

```
23592960

Started: 0 - 12:58:26
Ended: 13:00:51
877920256 (difference 854'327'296)

Started: 1 - 13:00:51
Ended: 13:03:39
1559494656 (difference 681'574'400)
```

and with variables cleaning

```
23592960

Started: 0 - 12:47:57
Ended: 12:50:20
877920256 (difference 854'327'296)

Started: 1 - 12:50:20
Ended: 12:53:16
1559756800 (difference 681'836'544)
```

Based on my reading PHP has a lot reason to leak memory... like this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48781

There is a tool called valgrind it can help, gone to try it :)

Comment: If you're using memory_get_peak_usage(true) to test your memory usage after unset, and it doesn't seem to be going down; then the clue is in the word __PEAK__

Comment: @MarkBaker I've tried to use simple memory_get_usage() picture the same in each iteration memory usage is growing up

Answer (score 3):

Although unset() does not free the memory consumed by the PHP process, it does free it for use by the PHP script itself.

So, if you are creating a variable of 10M of size 10 times in a loop and unsetting (or rewriting) it at the end of the loop, the memory consumption should be as low as 10M + all other variables by the end of the loop.

If it grows - then, there is a leak somewhere in the full logic you don't want to show.

Comment: leak ? hm .. how ? for example ? what should I search for ?

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP does it automatically.
When variable is not used any more, PHP unsets it itself.

Answer (score 0):

Because `unset` doesn't free up memory. It merely frees the variable. But if that variable points to some sort of complex structure, that PHP's memory management can't figure out how to free up, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

```
$vars_at_end = array_diff($vars_at_start, array_keys(get_defined_vars()));
foreach($vars_at_end as $v) unset($v);
unset($vars_at_end);
```

This whole block of code is working on copies (or even copies of copies) of your variables, so it's adding large amounts of memory.
All that you ever unset are the copies of copies in the foreach loop.

You need to unset the actual variables that you use

Comment: it's about 200 variables this is why i decided to do not write them all manually :) but as everyone suggest bellow, problem not in that, unset can't help

Answer (score 0):

BTW, your foreach ... unset loop does nothing anyway.  PHP uses a reference-based delayed copy-on write system to optimise memory use. This foreach loop this in effect a no-op.  Storage is freed -- that is returned to the internal Zend Engines emalloc allocator (*not* to the OS) -- or reuse once the reference count for any element is zero.  This will happen anyway for local variables when you leave the scope of a function and for class properties when you destroy a class object.  There is no point in cloning a shallow copy of a variable and then unsetting this as this just does a +1 -1 on the reference count.

If you mine the code for the main variables used in the loop and unset *them* then you will truly decrement reference counts and to 0, then you will free up storage for reuse.  However, as troelskyn implies, there are many ways the existing code can leave data elements with a non-zero reference.  The classic way is if your code is using references than you can create cyclic reference chains which will never be reclaimed unless the cycle is explicitly broken.  Even having a global array which is use to hold results can hog memory.

Sorry, but your statement:

> I don't want to show here full logic because it can take a lot of time for other peoples, it's not the main point here.

is wrong.   In PHP if you want to understand why you are not returning storage into the memory pool, then you *must* look into the code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you please clarify next sentence ? "If you mine the code for the main variables used in the loop and unset them" could you show small example ?

Comment: Let's say you have a results array, `$results` where the code is aggregating data, the you need to derefence the hash that `$results` is using, e.g. `$results = array();` will trigger a zend_hash_destroy() on the hash in the `$results` ZVAL.  The foreach is the same as `$v=$results; unset($v);` which does nothing.

Comment: it means that i can't use foreach to unset variables, and it will work if I will mention all variables somehow directly in unset without foreach help, right ?

Comment: "all variables" -- no you're missing the point here.  A scalar variable only takes up 32 bytes or so and will be reused anyway.  It's the hashtables (in objects and arrays) that could cause this.  Sorry but you've got to look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

unset() on a variable marks it for 'garbage collection'

Have you tried __destruct() ?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php